# How to configure SonarQube to make us increase the coverage?

Tags: sonarqube

To motivate ourselves to increase code coverage of unit tests, we have defined this rules for coverage:

1. overall code coverage must be > 80%
2. overall code coverage must not be less than the last time
3. code coverage on new code must be > 90%

To fulfill rules 1 and 2 I configured a Quality Gate with these conditions:

- "Coverage - value - is less than - 80"
- "Coverage - delta since previous analysis - is less than - 0"

For rule 3 I think that the following condition would meet it: "Coverage on new code - value - is less than - 90". But it is not possible to choose a value for this condition, only a delta. What is the meaning of a delta here? New code shouldn't have a delta, because it's new. How must i configure the condition to fulfil rule 3?

Comment: I will answer you initial question ("How to configure sonarqube to make us increase the coverage?"), please ask the question on the Google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube) for what seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

By default, SonarQube comes with a predefined Quality Gate that is designed to achieve exactly what you want: progressively make you increase your code coverage.

You can take a look at this ["SonarQube way" quality gate on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/quality_gates/show/4).

[image: Default "SonarQube way" quality gate]

The important line is the one which is highlighted on the screenshot. It means: "The code introduced since the beginning of developments on the current version must be covered at least at 80%". If you admit that you are constantly refactoring and rewriting parts of your code, then ultimately your code will be covered at least at 80%.